# How to do partial clone from gerrit 3.6.0

Tags: git, clone, gerrit, partial

I am trying to use partial clone with Gerrit,

clone works fine , but checkout gives an error :

fatal: remote error: want 85e34e76d94cdcfa914ceed78441be5ea98247cd not valid

error: invalid object 100644 85e34e76d94cdcfa914ceed78441be5ea98247cd for some_file

fatal: internal server error

I'm using gerrit 3.6.0

### my actions :

git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout my_repo

git co some_sha1

### my jgit.config :

```
[receive]
        autogc = false
[protocol]
        version = 2
[uploadpack]
    allowAnySHA1InWant = true
    allowFilter = true
```

didnot find anything on google,

does gerrit support partial clone ?

10x
Lior.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that gerrit does not support the uploadPack.allowAnySHA1InWant configuration.

Here is the feature patch: https://git.eclipse.org/r/c/jgit/jgit/+/180794

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Git 2.34.1 and Gerrit 3.5.1

When I execute the following command:

```
git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/REPO
```

The clone works but I see the following warning:

```
warning: filtering not recognized by server, ignoring
```

So, I think Gerrit doesn't support partial clones.

Comment: you have to add this to jgit.config :

[uploadpack]
    allowAnySHA1InWant = true
    allowFilter = true

Comment: I'm using Git, not JGit.

Comment: yes , but Gerrit server uses JGIT.
if you add the uploadpack config (as in the orig quetion) , you wont get the warning , and partial clone will work(if you do --no-checkout), but checkout afterwards will fail.